# Azure FunctionApp without functions after successful CI/CD over Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I've created an Azure Function App (Linux) running on an App Service Plan Y1 and have my sources in Azure DevOps Git. The functions are written in C# on DOTNET 6.

Below you can see my YAML definitions for the CI and a separated CD pipeline. When I execute the pipeline everything works well (both are green). After the deployment however this is how my Azure Portal looks in the `Functions` blade:

[image: Azure Portal]

Using the VS Code Azure Extension and looking into the files of the function app I get:

[image: 404 for bin]

When I look in the artifact of the CI pipeline everything looks good (explorer view of the downloaded zip):

[image: ZIP Content]

The `bin`-folder is populated there.

Some key points:

- I have no slots in the function app.
- The deployments are visible in the associated App Insights.
- My reference point is [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml%2Ccsharp)

So is it normal to get the 404 when searching in VS code and did somebody experience something similar or even know the solution?

Sidenote:

I used to deploy my function using VS Code with extensions install. Today I now get a weired error message after the deployment:

[image: Telemetry error in VS Code]

CI YAML

```yaml
pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

trigger: none

variables:
    - name: 'Solution'
      value: '**/MyProject.sln'
    - name: 'ProjectFilter'
      value: '**/*.csproj'    
    - name: 'BuildConfiguration'
      value: 'Release'

steps:   
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use DotNet 6
      inputs:
          version: '6.0.x'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore
      inputs:
          command: restore
          projects: '$(ProjectFilter)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
          projects: '$(ProjectFilter)'
          arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'    
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish Image Converter
      inputs:
          command: publish
          projects: src/Functions/**/MyProject.csproj
          publishWebProjects: false
          arguments: '--no-restore --no-build --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/function_publish_output'
          zipAfterPublish: false
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: Archive Image Converter
      inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/function_publish_output'
          includeRootFolder: false
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyProject.zip'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

CD YAML

```yaml
variables:
  - name: 'vmImageName'
    value: 'ubuntu-latest'
  - name: 'serviceConnectionName'
    value: 'MYCONN'
  - name: 'project'
    value: 'MYPROJECT'

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: ci
      source: 'NAMEOFCI'
      trigger: true

pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)

trigger: none

stages:
  - stage: Production
    displayName: Production
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: 'Deploy'
        environment: 'Production'
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - download: ci
                  displayName: 'Download Artifact'
                  artifact: drop
                - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
                  displayName: 'Deploy Image Converter Function'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: '$(serviceConnectionName)'
                    appType: functionAppLinux
                    appName: 'fapp-**********-prod'
                    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ci/drop/MyProject.zip'
                    runtimeStack: 'DOTNET|6.0'
```

**UPDATE**

I decided to redeploy my function and could deploy using VS Code directly again when switching from Y1 to S1. Using the Azure DevOps Pipeline still gives me a green checkmark there but no function triggers visible in the portal. Switching back to Y1 brings the error in VS Code back.

Answer (score 1):

we had a similar issue and had to add a parameter to app settings. In our case directly via terraform.

```
app_settings = {
 WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = "1"
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried this and it didn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what exactly you see on the file system? You can use console or Advanced tools:

[image]

Comment: I don't have this option in the Azure Portal. I think because I'm sitting on a Y-service-plan.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt you're right.... the console is not available for the linux instance ...

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt Before deploying the function either through vs code or pipelines, add the application setting 'SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT' to true in the function Configuration in portal.

Comment: @PravallikaKV I added the setting. My pipeline runs for 22 minutes now :-(. I switched to App Service S1 plan and will later update my question accordingly providing more info about the file system.